# Alchemy API in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ibm-cloud, sentiment-analysis, alchemyapi

Is it possible to use the Alchemy API in Matlab? I want to call the `URLGetTextSentiment` method, without using other IDE's.
Would be great if you have some experience with that and share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlchemyAPI provides REST API endpoints for all text-mining and content analysis functionality. You can call those REST APIs from wherever you need, once you know your API key. In Matlab you can interact with RESTful web services using [*webread*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webread.html) and [*webwrite*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/webwrite.html).